# how to use ng-mask in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

how to use ng-mask for validation of phone number having pattern (xxx)xxx-xxxx . I tried using "pattern" in the input html tag but not satisfied with the result
 because each time when user enters the phone number, the user must type both '()' and '-',and this will make the user annoying. So suggest a way to overcome this.

```
<input type="tel" name="phoneno" maxlength=13 ng-model="phone.number" pattern="^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$" required/></div>
```

Comment: you could do this by creating a directive

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.number" name="phone" mask="(999) 999-9999" clean="true" ng-model="phone">
```

Comment: Will it generate () and '-' automatically or user must input it

Comment: Automatically. Check out [this link](http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/) and search for phone number

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't display the '()' '-' automatically it behaves like a normal text box @DustinToothless

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angularJS, you must use ng-mask and mask together, and mask has his own structure I will write an input for you to have a better concept and vision :

```
<input type="text" name="Hour" ng-model="Hour" placeholder="00:00" ng-mask mask="#00:00" />
```